# what is kernel headers 3.3.2-6.fc16.i686.PAE : Unable to start the VMWare

Tags: linux, fedora, vmware-workstation

I installed `VMWare workstation 6.5.0` for linux *(fedora)*. But when i run it this screen pops up :

[image]

and i am unable to start vmware. I googled it and couldn't find much except for this :

```
yum install kmod-ndiswrapper-3.3.2-6.fc16.i686.PAE
```

Nothing changed after this. What is the problem ? What do i need to do to start the `vmware` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `kernel-header` and 'kernel-devel' packages, assuming you have the latest kernel for your version of fedora.

```
yum -y install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

should do the trick

Then rerun the vmware workstation installer. I vaguely seem to recall there was a config script called `vmware-config.pl` that would just compile was was needed as well, but vmware's docs don't seem to agree with that.

Comment: how do i install that ?

Comment: i have installed the headers using the command you gave and then restarted the installed application _(VMWare)_ but the problem persists

Comment: restarted or reinstalled?

Comment: restarted the application. Do i need to reinstall ?

Comment: "Then rerun the vmware workstation installer" = reinstall the application

Comment: getting the same message. What could be the reason ? I think of manually giving the path by clicking browse. Where can i find those files.

Comment: Try invoking /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl amd see if its better.Else  Kernel source is usually inside /usr/src/kernels/

Comment: [i don't see vmware-config.pl](http://i45.tinypic.com/mcayp5.png)